# Go to next page without using the same tags as the index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, document-body

I am trying to code a java script function for my page. The "index.html" page has the basic layout with all the necessary tags (html, head, title and body). My question is, how will I go to the next page (if you click on a menu item) without having to code the same tags and copy all the data from the "index.html" page - i.e. not having redundant code.

e.g. There are 3 main pages excluding the "index.html" page (this one has all the main tags on it). The other pages are 1-About 2-Contact 3-Gallery. On each page the tags will only have:

Bla bla bla

some other tags with text, photos etc

What is the code for the java script function to change the text/content within the  tags  without having to copy the entire document's code on each page?

I want to use Chrome as the default browser and I am only using HTML and Java script (no PHP)

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried yourself? When you googled for information, what results did you get and why did it not fit your requirements?

Comment: You might be looking for the innerHTML property for a DOM object. Where do you have the other content (1-About 2-Contact 3-Gallery) located at? Are you going to lazy-load these from the server or are they just hidden and you want to show them?

Comment: Why won't you use PHP?

Comment: @MjrKusanagi I almost added a toggle function for display from none to block. This would be easier no?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this function this will solve your problem just pass your div Id where you want to load the contents of page with index layout. In my example i load my contents in container div.

```
/**
     * Load page into url
     *
     * @param url           The url to load
     * @param onleave       The function to call before leaving
     * @param onenter       The function to call after loading
     */
function loadPage(url, onleave, onenter) 

{
    alert(url);
    console.log("loadPage("+url+")");

    // If onleave function specified
    if (onleave) {
        onleave();
    }

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4){
            if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                console.log("Received content"+xmlhttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                // If onenter function specified
                if (onenter) {
                    onenter();
                }
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "Error loading page " + url;
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return;
}
```

Comment: this will 100% solve you issue of loading contents with layout that you defined in index.html page

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
function menuClick(x) {
    if(x == "About"){
        var menu1 = document.getElementById("menuButton_1");
        menu1.innerHTML = "The HTML content for your about section";
    } else if (){
        // replicate the same for your other two menu sections
        // here #2
    } else if() {
        // here #3
    }
}
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<div id="menuButton_1" onclick="menuClick('About')">
</div>
<div id="menuButton_2" onclick="menuClick('Contact')">
</div>
<div id="menuButton_3" onclick="menuClick('Gallery')">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can execute an "onclick" function to fire when your menu buttons are clicked. In your javascript function you can test which menu button was clicked and set the innerHTML of particular elements on the page to show the correct content.

You can change the content of multiple elements by targeting each of their id's. Just create more javascript variables and use them to target the innerHTML of the specific HTML elements you want to change.

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but this answer doesn't include "code for the JavaScript function" as the poster requested. Also, if you want to know "Why no PHP?", add a comment. What you've posted is a clarification request, not an answer.

Comment: @MjrKusanagi I've adjusted my answer. Thank you for keeping me on my toes and being professional about it.